# classList.toggle in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, toggle, contains

I'm trying to assign .hidden to certain elemement when class is not present and remove class .hidden if this class is already assigned to this element. In other words - I just want to toggle class.

I wrote code

```
var isHidden = document.getElementById("inputSelected").classList.toggle("hidden");
```

but it doesn't work. But when I console log classList.contains

```
var isHidden = document.getElementById("inputSelected").classList.contains("hidden");
```

it returns false - which means, that this class it not assigned. So why it doesn't toggle?

More code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Kalkulator dat</title>
<meta name="description" content="Kalkulator dat. Ile dni minęło od wskazanej daty? Jaka będzie data za daną ilość dni?">
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Kalkulator dat</h1>
<div id="daysPassed">
    <h2>Ile pełnych dni minęło?</h2>
    <form id=daysPassedForm">
        <label for="firstDateDP">Data początkowa:</label>
        <input type="date" id="firstDate">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="radio" id="toToday" name="todayOrSelected">    
            <label for="toToday">Do dziś</label>

            <input type="radio" id="toSelected" name="todayOrSelected"> 
            <label for="toSelected">Do wskazanej daty</label> 
            <p id="inputSelected">(<input type="date" id="selectedEndDate">)</p>

        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Oblicz">
        </form>
</div>

<div id="daysPassedResult" class="result">
    <p id="daysPassedInfo">Od wskazanej daty minęło x dni</p>
</div>

<div id="dateIndicate">
    <h2>Jaka będzie data?</h2>
    <form id="dateIndicateForm">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="firstDateDI"><span>Data początkowa:</span></label>
                <input type="date" id="firstDateDI">
            </li>

            <li>
            <label for="numberOfDays"><span>Liczba pełnych dni:</span></label>
            <input type="number" id="numberOfDays" step="1">
            </li>

            <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Oblicz">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="dateIndicateResult" class="result">
    <p id="dateIndicateResult">Po x dniach od y będzie</p>
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
margin-bottom: 7px;
}

body {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 40%;
background-color: #FFCA51;
}

div {
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 15px;
}

p {
margin: 8px 0 8px 0;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;}

fieldset {
border: none;
}

input {
margin: 2px;
padding: 1px;
}

span {
width: 115px;
text-align: right;
display: inline-block;
}


#daysPassed {
background-color: #E8A849;
padding-left: 16px;
}

#inputSelected {
margin: 0 0 0 8px;
display: inline-block;
}

#daysPassedResult {
background-color: #FFA75D;
}

#dateIndicate {
background-color: #E87A49;
padding-left: 16px;
margin-top: 20px;
}

#dateIndicateResult {
background-color: #FF6D51;
}

.result {
margin: 8px 0 8px 16px;
padding-left: 12px;
max-width: 50%;
}

.hidden {
display: none;}


function preparePage() {
    document.getElementById("inputSelected").classList.toggle("hidden");
    document.getElementById("daysPassedResult").classList.toggle("hidden");
    document.getElementById("dateIndicateResult").classList.toggle("hidden");
}

window.onload = function() {
    preparePage();
};
```

Right now second and third line of preparePage works, but first (#inputselected) doesn't

Comment: why are you mixing javascript with jquery?

Comment: classList is a jquery? I thought it is just javascript... Isn't it in jquery toggleClass()?

Comment: I's tlking about `document.getElementById`

Comment: @Mritunjay: there is no jQuery on this example.

Comment: How do you know it "doesn't work"?

Comment: @FelixKling - it doesn't work because class is not added :)

Comment: Well, `classList.toggle` definitely works (http://jsfiddle.net/qdmdke0z/). If you can't provide a complete example which replicates the issue, then we can't really help you.

Comment: @FelixKling I added full code. Could you take a look?

Comment: I solved it. I couldn't apply display:none to p in a class. I made a div around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) Reference from Mozilla:

> `toggle ( token )` - removes `token` from string and returns false. If `token` doesn't exist it's added and the function returns true

Your code actually works, but it seems that the issue is not caused by the DOMTokenList `.toggle()` function, but by a CSS id `#inputSelected`:

```
#inputSelected {
  margin: 0 0 0 8px;
  display: inline-block; /* will never let .hidden to actually set the "display: none". */
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

A simple way to fix it is to define:

```
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

or define `display: inline-block;` in a separate class.

If the problem really is the `.toggle`, `DOMTokenList` still has:

- `.contains`
- `.add`
- `.remove`

Otherwise, you can use jQuery or manage the `element.className` by hand.